# Find the Laplace transform of $f(t)=\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{t}}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to calculate the Laplace transform of :

\begin{equation}
f(t)=\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{t}}
\end{equation}

It necessitates to make the following conversion $\sin t=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$, then we obtain, by the Laplace transform formula $\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$:

\begin{equation}
f(s)=\int_0^\infty t^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sin t\ e^{-st}\ dt=\int_0^\infty t^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}\  e^{-st}\ dt
\end{equation}

We then split it up in two integrals:

\begin{equation}
f(s)=\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty t^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{(-s+i)t}  dt-\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty t^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{(-s-i)t}  dt
\end{equation}

So here the primary choice from the Laplace transform table would be $t^ne^{at}=\frac{n!}{(s-a)^{n+1}}$, with $t=-1/2$ and $a=s+i$ for the former, and $a=s-i$ for the latter. But that doesn't work, since we get $-1/2!$, which is not defined.

A solution proposed in an exam is to use the transform for $t^{-1/2}=(\frac{\pi}{s})^{\frac{1}{2}}$. But how can that work, when the expression is clearly not only $t^{-1/2}$ but a product of $t^{-1/2}$ and $e^{(s\pm i)t}$?

This transform seems inconclusive from the given expressions in the table.

Any ideas?

Thanks

UPDATE:
Using the correct result of $(-1/2)!=\Gamma(1/2)$ we get:

$t^ne^{at}=\frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{(-s-s+i)^{n+1}}$

this gives:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty t^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{(-s+i)t}  dt=\frac{1}{2i}\frac{\Gamma(-1/2)}{(-s-s+i)^{n+1}}=\frac{\Gamma(-1/2)}{(i-2s)^{1/2}}
\end{equation}

for the second integral

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty t^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{(-s-i)t}  dt=-\frac{1}{2i}\frac{\Gamma(-1/2)}{(-s-s-i)^{n+1}}=-\frac{\Gamma(-1/2)}{(-i-2s)^{1/2}}
\end{equation}

Comment: $(-1/2)!=\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$, see [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: I did the mistake on relying on my Casio  fx-991ES PLUS. But does this mean the latter method is wrong?

Comment: The solution of the exam meant $\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^{ - 1/2} e^{ - st} dt}  = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{s}}$ for $\Re(s)>0$. Use it with $s=s\pm i$.

Comment: By the way, the Laplace transform is $\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st}dt$ and not $\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{st}dt$.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was a typo (big one)

Comment: @Gary why would one assume that $\Re(s)>0$, when nothing else is said?

Comment: Well, do you think the integral converges if $\Re s \leq 0$? Put for example $s=0$ or $s=-1$, i.e., do $\int_0^\infty  {t^{ - 1/2} dt} ,\; \int_0^\infty  {t^{ - 1/2} e^t dt}$ converge?

Comment: You need to add an s to that t in the exponent. But my answer is, I have no idea. By what it seems, it does not converge, but I can't see that on first glance, and neither on second glance.

Comment: I do not need to add $s$ because $s=-1$ in the second integral. And yes, these integrals are divergent. For instance $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^{ - 1/2} dt}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{T \to  + \infty } \int_0^T {t^{ - 1/2} dt}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{T \to  + \infty } 2\sqrt T  =  + \infty 
$$ and the second one is much more obvious.

Comment: Thanks, I see that now, as you corrected my point on the s.

Comment: The thing is that Laplace transforms converge in half planes. You should known this if you study Laplace transforms. They did not tell you?

Comment: No, I don't have any lectures, only reading books. Does this mean, that I always want to consider the case of $\Re(s)>0$, if something is in doubt?

Comment: Well if for example $f(t)=e^{ct}$, you want to consider $\Re s >c$.

Comment: Well noted. Thanks!