# Substituting $it+\ln t$ with $u$ in challenging integration procedure

Tags: integration, substitution

Regarding this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4367362/find-the-laplace-transform-of-ft-frac-sin-t-sqrtt)

I would like to ask the community for hints regarding this problem.  Since the steps done on that original post, did not yield the correct result, I have done a different approach.

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{t}}dt=\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{\sqrt{t}}dt
\end{equation}

for simplicity we split in two integrals, and solve the first here, which gives the solution to the second too

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{it}}{\sqrt{t}}dt=\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln t}e^{it}dt=\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty e^{{\frac{1}{2}\ln t}+it}dt
\end{equation}

So we want to solve this now,

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty e^{{\frac{1}{2}\ln t}+it}dt
\end{equation}

and it is tempting to set $u=\frac{1}{2}\ln t+it$, but then $du=\frac{1}{2t}+i$, so we can't get rid of that $t$ in the substitution.

Alternatively, we can write $e^{it}=z$, and form the complex integral

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty \sqrt{t}z dz
\end{equation}

But here we need to change the t-variable into a complex variable. So I suggest doing a Möbius transformation on of t, but since it is real, it doesn't apply.

Is there any chance here to solve this by some other way, or use this with some modifications?

Comment: $(\sin t)/\sqrt t$ does not have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Mathematica cannot integrate $e^{it}/\sqrt t$ without resorting to the imaginary error function. To me this suggests that the function has no primitive in terms of elementary functions. You can still evaluate  certain definite integrals (like over $[0,\infty)$) by other means.

Comment: It would be nice to see how one gets the error function from this integral. Otherwise, if Mathematica can't do it, how can we? PS; This is from 0 to infty, just added the limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I should do is to simplify the problem using $t=x^2$
$$I=\frac{1}{2i}\int \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt=-\frac i 2\int  \left(e^{i x^2}-e^{-i x^2}\right)\,dx$$ which are quite standard since
$$\int e^{a x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2 \sqrt{a}}\text{erfi}\left(x\sqrt{a} \right)$$ where appears the imaginary error function (which is not elementary).

So
$$I=-i\frac { \sqrt \pi} 4\Bigg[\frac{\text{erfi}\left(x\sqrt{i} \right)}{\sqrt{i}} -\frac{\text{erfi}\left(x\sqrt{-i} \right)}{\sqrt{-i}} \Bigg]$$

Comment: Great idea, thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Another more elegant approach uses the substitution $u=\sqrt{t}$, which gives

$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{t}}dt=2 \int_0^\infty\sin(u^2)du.
$$

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Limits_as_x_approaches_infinity) the righthand side is the limit of Fresnel integrals and is convergent. The limit can be found as explained there.